# Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop' is not available on this platform

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone help me I don't know what happened I was just pubUpgrade and it become like this

[image]

I've tried flutter clean and tried to delete dart:js line in js.dart but still not work thanks for your help if someone could help me I'll be grateful.

Comment: search your files for import 'dart:js_interop` and delete it, sometimes IDE imports it.

Comment: Please copy the error in text format instead of a image.

Comment: after a while when I try to remove  'dart:js_interop' line again it work fine. thank you

Comment: I noticed it happening when I opened my flutter project on a Windows 10 machine in vscode. I usually develop on my iMac.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be related to the emulator you are using, you can try to run your application in the web version, if it works, I recommend you check your emulator.

Comment: thank you. it's fixed after I delete the 'dart:js' line in the file that I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:- Try to remove imports of 'dart:js_interop' as it may be imported by default in many of your project files.

Method 2:- NOTE that this import are certainly due to usage of StreamBuilder in your app , so try to use any alternative widgets to do the same work inorder to solve your problem if NOT solved by first method. .